# Will Visual Studio compile and debug faster with a large amount of ram?

Tags: memory

I’ve spent the past four years developing an Enterprise app. It usually requires six instances of Visual Studio (running in debug mode) simultaneously.  Also, a few docker containers. I reached a point where my i7 laptop would crash and built a desktop with a 9920x processor and 64 gigs ram.  It runs great.  Big time saver (especially for compiling the Xamarin components).

If I maxed out the motherboard to 128 gigs, would I see a speed performance in compiling Visual Studio (C#) code, or would it be a waste of money?  I know it all depends on the amount of resources being used by the apps. I am interested in knowing if Visual Studio can optimize its performance by using more ram and caching files to disk,  less (though the disks are M.2 SSD and pretty fast).  Thanks!

Comment: Compiling is typically heavier on the CPU than RAM...I guess my best advice is to crack open task manager or so and check what if anything is spiking, that will tell you if it's worth your effort or not.  I'd imagine the docker containers and the actual instances of vis studio are eating up more in terms of memory than the compiling is (likely by a significant amount)

Comment: Debugging won't speed up with more RAM. Why would it? You're stepping through code in small sections (often line by line) and stopping How would RAM make that any faster?

Comment: Sorry, I've been a coder for 35+ years and this may be "old guy" thinking. Source code debuggers used to swap code in and out of memory. The slow-down was caused by "thrashing" (you would stare at the blinking led on the hd). This is what happened on my I7 laptop (16 gigs memory). I don't know what it was writing, but it was constantly writing to its disk.  Xamarin swaps lots of files when building Android, IOS and UWP apps. The question is more about if VS is smart enough to cache in memory when its available.